# How to split a string into consecutive substrings of length at most 3 in all possible ways?

Tags: ruby, variables

I am trying to take a string, between length 1 and 10, and output all possible ways of breaking up the string into consecutive substrings that are of sizes 1, 2, or 3. For example:

`Input: 123456`

Slice the integer into individual characters, then proceed through to find combinations.
The code would return all of the following arrays.

```
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  
    [12, 3, 4, 5, 6]  
    [1, 23, 4, 5, 6]  
    [1, 2, 34, 5, 6]  
    [1, 2, 3, 45, 6]  
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 56]  
    [12, 34, 5, 6]  
    [12, 3, 45, 6]  
    [12, 3, 4, 56]  
    [1, 23, 45, 6]  
    [1, 2, 34, 56]  
    [1, 23, 4, 56]  
    [12, 34, 56]  
    [123, 4, 5, 6]  
    [1, 234, 5, 6]  
    [1, 2, 345, 6]  
    [1, 2, 3, 456]  
    [123, 456]  
    [1, 23, 456]  
    [1, 234, 56]  
    [12, 345, 6]  
    [12, 3, 456]  
    [123, 4, 56]  
    [123, 45, 6]
```

I'm trying to do this in ruby. Thanks!

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: The input needs to be broken down into blocks that are max size 3. For example [1234,5,6] wouldn't work because the first item is too large.

I've been working on permutations and combinations, but can't figure out how to get permutations containing different sized blocks (some with 1 character, some with 2 and some with 3). I've also started working on a decision tree, but haven't gotten very far.

Comment: @Richard: This has nothing to do with permutations. A permutation is a re-ordering. You are keeping the numbers in the same order.

Comment: @Peng -- you're right.  But I wonder if permutations might actually end up in the solution, obliquely ... still thinking, but very late where I am...

Comment: @Andy: Absolutely not. He only needs to find positions to break the string. There is nothing being permuted here. He was 9 places for `,`s to go, and wants to choose them so that at most 3 numbers appear between. The numbers stay in order.

Comment: Try recursion. If the length of the string should always be small, I think it won't eat all your stack.

Comment: I'm not going to solve it immediately, but I'd start by trying to think of it recursively based on length. I.e., if you have a solution for a string of length n, can you get from that to a solution for a string of length n+1 easily?

Comment: The numbers stay in order, but I'm thinking that the positions of the splits might follow a rule that can be played using permutation.  Remember, he only has 9 possible places for a split to go because this example is ten digits long; it doesn't have to be. ... and yes, I'm seeing this as something that might fit a recursive pattern, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working function. May be not optimal as I didn't spend much time on it.

```
str = "1234567890"

def f(s, n)
    return [[]] if s.empty?

    (1..[n, s.length].min).map{|c| f(s[c..-1], n).map{|a| [s[0, c]] + a}}.inject(&:+)
end

puts f(str, 3).collect{|l| l * "\t"}
```

EDIT: Made it a bit shorter and the length is now passed as second parameter to function for flexibility.

Comment: I'd recommend using `.map{... if ...}.compact` for style.

Comment: Fixed. It looks really cryptic :) Ruby is a wonderful language.

Answer (score 3):

It took me quite a while to figure this out, its a much harder problem then I first though. But eventually I hit upon this solution:

```
def combinations(s)
  c = (s.length > 3) ? [] : [[s]]
  max = [4, s.length].min
  (1...max).inject(c) do |c, i|
    combinations(s[i..-1]).inject(c) do |c, tail|
      c.push([s[0...i]] + tail)
    end
  end
end

combinations("12345").each { |c| p c }
```

Produces:

```
["1", "2", "345"]
["1", "2", "3", "45"]
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
["1", "2", "34", "5"]
["1", "23", "45"]
["1", "23", "4", "5"]
["1", "234", "5"]
["12", "345"]
["12", "3", "45"]
["12", "3", "4", "5"]
["12", "34", "5"]
["123", "45"]
["123", "4", "5"]
```

Comment: This is not the output that the OP is after.

Comment: It isn't?  Why?  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another:

```
class String
  def splitup(prefix=nil)
    parts = []
    if size <= 3
      parts << [prefix,self].compact * ","
    end
    (1..([size,3].min)).each do |p|
      next if p >= size
      parts << slice(p..-1).splitup([prefix,slice(0,p)].compact * ",")
    end
    parts
  end

  def report
    flat = splitup.flatten.sort_by {|x| [-x.size,x]}
    puts
    puts "#{flat.size} permutations of #{self}"
    puts flat
  end
end
```

and then

```
>> "123456".report

24 permutations of 123456
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,56
1,2,3,45,6
1,2,34,5,6
1,23,4,5,6
12,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,456
1,2,34,56
1,2,345,6
1,23,4,56
1,23,45,6
1,234,5,6
12,3,4,56
12,3,45,6
12,34,5,6
123,4,5,6
1,23,456
1,234,56
12,3,456
12,34,56
12,345,6
123,4,56
123,45,6
123,456
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(s, mx)
  (1..[s.size, mx].min).each_with_object([]) do |n,a|
     if n < s.size
       sf = s[0, n]
       f(s[n..-1], mx).each { |c| a << [sf, *c] }
     else
       a << [s]
     end
  end
end
```

```
f("12345", 3)
  #=> [["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], ["1", "2", "3", "45"],
  #    ["1", "2", "34", "5"], ["1", "2", "345"], ["1", "23", "4", "5"],
  #    ["1", "23", "45"], ["1", "234", "5"], ["12", "3", "4", "5"],
  #    ["12", "3", "45"], ["12", "34", "5"], ["12", "345"],
  #    ["123", "4", "5"], ["123", "45"]] => [["1", "2", "3", "4"],
  #    ["1", "2", "34"], ["1", "23", "4"], ["1", "234"],
  #    ["12", "3", "4"], ["12", "34"], ["123", "4"]]
```