# possible ways of splitting a string into n substrings

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I'm trying to write a method that would take 'abcd' as an input, and return:

```
["a b c d", "a b cd", "a bc d", "a bcd", "ab c d", "ab cd", "abc d", "abcd"]
```

so, all possible ways of splitting a string into n substrings that when you concatenage s1 + s2 + s3 + ... you get back the original string.

I have solved it like this, but I feel like there should be a faster and more straightforward way to do it.

```
def sequence(n)
  [true, false].repeated_permutation(n).to_a
end

def breakdown4(string)
  guide = sequence(string.length-1)
  arr = []
  guide.each do |i|
    s = string.dup
    counter = 0
    i.each do |j|
      if j
        s.insert(counter+1, " ")
        p counter
        counter += 2
      else
        counter += 1
      end
    end
    arr.push(s)
  end
  arr
end
```

any suggestions?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851706/how-to-split-a-string-into-consecutive-substrings-of-length-at-most-3-in-all-pos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = 'abcd'

s[1..-1].each_char.reduce([s[0]]) do |arr, c|
  space_c = " #{c}" 
  arr.flat_map { |str| [str + c, str + space_c] }
end
  # => ["abcd", "abc d", "ab cd", "ab c d", "a bcd", "a bc d", "a b cd", "a b c d"]
```

Here's another way (stuffing spaces into the string).

```
arr = (1..s.size-1).to_a
  #=> [1, 2, 3]
s.size.times.flat_map do |n|
  arr.combination(n).map do |locs|
    scopy = s.dup
    locs.reverse_each { |idx| scopy.insert(idx, ' ') }
    scopy
  end
end  
  #=> ["abcd", "a bcd", "ab cd", "abc d", "a b cd", "a bc d", "ab c d", "a b c d"]
```

Answer (score 5):

A oneliner also using `repeated_permutation` (which I just learned from you :-):

```
s = 'abcd'

[' ', ''].repeated_permutation(s.size - 1).map { |j| s.chars.zip(j).join }
=> ["a b c d", "a b cd", "a bc d", "a bcd", "ab c d", "ab cd", "abc d", "abcd"]
```

- `repeated_permutation` produces joints, like `[" ", "", " "]`.
- `zip` pairs them to the letters, like `[["a", " "], ["b", ""], ["c", " "], ["d", nil]]`.
- `join` turns all parts into strings and joins them, like `"a bc d"`.

(Note that `nil` becomes the empty string and that [`join` works recursively](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/trunk/Array.html#method-i-join), effectively flattening the whole structure).

---

Previous solutions I came up with before I knew `repeated_permutation`:

```
[s[0]].product(*s[1..-1].chars.flat_map { |c| [[' ', ''], [c]] }).map(&:join)
=> ["a b c d", "a b cd", "a bc d", "a bcd", "ab c d", "ab cd", "abc d", "abcd"]

s[1..-1].chars.reduce([s[0]]) { |m, c| m.product([' ', ''], [c]) }.map(&:join)
=> ["a b c d", "a b cd", "a bc d", "a bcd", "ab c d", "ab cd", "abc d", "abcd"]

[''].product(*([[' ', '']] * s.size.pred)).map { |j| s.gsub('') { j.shift } }
=> ["a b c d", "a b cd", "a bc d", "a bcd", "ab c d", "ab cd", "abc d", "abcd"]

(0...2**s.size).step(2).map { |i| s.gsub(/(?!^)/) { ' ' * (1 & i /= 2) } }
=> ["abcd", "a bcd", "ab cd", "a b cd", "abc d", "a bc d", "ab c d", "a b c d"]
```

The basic idea of all of them is like this (using the hardcoded string for clarity):

```
['a'].product([' ', ''], ['b'], [' ', ''], ['c'], [' ', ''], ['d']).map(&:join)
=> ["a b c d", "a b cd", "a bc d", "a bcd", "ab c d", "ab cd", "abc d", "abcd"]
```

Comment: This is by far the prettiest answer! (repeated_permutation one), but I don't quite understand why it works...

Comment: Very clever, Stefan. A detail: you might replace `s.chars.zip(j).join` with, say, `arr.zip(j).join`, where `arr` has been previously defined `arr = s.chars`.

Comment: @NavidFallad I added some explanation, hope it's clear now? You can always play around with it, for example change the block to `{ |j| p s.chars.zip(j) }`, to see what's going on. And of course the documentation helps :-).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah, that makes it faster, but it's still among the slower ones, so I'm not trying to win a speed prize, just a brevity+clarity prize :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here are some comparisons between the different methods:

```
#navid
def sequence(n)
  [true, false].repeated_permutation(n).to_a
end

def breakdown4(string)
  guide = sequence(string.length-1)
  arr = []
  guide.each do |i|
    s = string.dup
    counter = 0
    i.each do |j|
      if j
        s.insert(counter+1, " ")
        #p counter
        counter += 2
      else
        counter += 1
      end
    end
    arr.push(s)
  end
  arr
end


#tom
def powerset(arr)
  a = [[]] 
  for i in 0...arr.size do
    len = a.size; j = 0;
    while j < len
      a << (a[j] + [arr[i]])
      j+=1
    end
  end
  a
end

def breakdown(string)
  indexes_lists = powerset((1..string.length-1).to_a)
  indexes_lists.map(&:reverse).map do |indexes_list|
    result = string.dup
    indexes_list.each { |i| result.insert(i, " ")}
    result
  end
end

#stefan
def stefan1 s
  [s[0]].product(*s[1..-1].chars.flat_map { |c| [[' ', ''], [c]] }).map(&:join)
end

def stefan2 s
  s[1..-1].chars.reduce([s[0]]) { |m, c| m.product([' ', ''], [c]) }.map(&:join)
end

def stefan3 s
  [''].product(*([[' ', '']] * s.size.pred)).map { |j| s.gsub('') { j.shift } }
end

def stefan4 s
  (0...2**s.size).step(2).map { |i| s.gsub(/(?!^)/) { ' ' * (1 & i /= 2) } }
end

def stefan5 s
  [' ', ''].repeated_permutation(s.size - 1).map { |j| s.chars.zip(j).join }
end

#cary
def cary s
  s[1..-1].each_char.reduce([s[0]]) do |arr, c|
    space_c = ' ' + c 
    arr.flat_map { |str| [str + c, str + space_c] }
  end
end

#cary2
def cary2 s
  arr = (1..s.size-1).to_a
    #=> [1, 2, 3]
  s.size.times.flat_map do |n|
    arr.combination(n).map do |locs|
      scopy = s.dup
      locs.reverse_each { |idx| scopy.insert(idx, ' ') }
      scopy
    end
end  
end
```

Results

```
require 'fruity'
str = 'abcd'

compare do
  navid    { s = str.dup; breakdown4(s) }
  tom      { s = str.dup; breakdown(s).sort }
  stefan_1 { s = str.dup; stefan1(s) }
  stefan_2 { s = str.dup; stefan2(s) }
  stefan_3 { s = str.dup; stefan3(s) }  
  stefan_4 { s = str.dup; stefan4(s).sort }
  stefan_5 { s = str.dup; stefan5(s) }
  cary_s   { s = str.dup; cary(s).reverse  }  
  cary_s2  { s = str.dup; cary2(s).sort  }  
end

#Running each test 64 times. Test will take about 1 second.
#cary_s is faster than navid by 2x ± 1.0
#navid is similar to tom
#tom is similar to cary_s2
#cary_s2 is similar to stefan_1
#stefan_1 is similar to stefan_2
#stefan_2 is faster than stefan_3 by 2x ± 1.0
#stefan_3 is similar to stefan_5
#stefan_5 is similar to stefan_4
```

Using a longer string:

```
str = 'abcdefghijklm'

#Running each test once. Test will take about 4 seconds.
#cary_s is faster than stefan_1 by 9x ± 1.0
#stefan_1 is similar to cary_s2
#cary_s2 is similar to navid
#navid is similar to tom
#tom is similar to stefan_2
#stefan_2 is faster than stefan_3 by 2x ± 1.0
#stefan_3 is similar to stefan_5
#stefan_5 is similar to stefan_4
```

Comment: For `stefan_3` you used `stefan2`. I btw added a fourth, now I don't know which is which :-). I don't think sorting should be included in the benchmark, that could contribute significantly to the times. Might even harm different solutions differently, depending on how sorted their results already are.

Comment: @StefanPochmann okay, updated. I had to sort Tom's answer else results were different.

Comment: This is a community wiki answer now. The test-code is linked in the answer if anyone thinks the tests need refining, feel free.

Comment: Ha... in your test-code I finally noticed Navid's use of `repeated_permutation`. That gave me my by far prettiest solution now...

Comment: Sagar, I don't expect my solution to be competitive, but could you add it to the benchmark?

Comment: @CarySwoveland updated. I used your second edit (now invisible) because it was faster than your current. Only applied a `sort` to some answers, so the results all match.

Comment: That was certainly fast work! I'm going to add another way to my answer. You may want to add that to the mix.

Comment: My method #2 is up now.

Comment: @CarySwoveland's doesn't need a `sort`, `reverse` is enough and causes much less overhead. Or he could use `[str + space_c, str + c]` to directly produce the "correct" order. Btw, while this "Fruity" output looks cute, I'd actually prefer cold hard numbers for everything, not just "similar". Especially when several "similar" get chained, as similarity doesn't sound transitive.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually quite a tricky problem... But after giving it some thought, here's a clever approach I came up with. It may not be the most *compact* (one-liner) solution; but it's quite instructive, could easily be rewritten in any language, and is non-wasteful.

Start by recognising that, given an input string of length `n`, there are `n-1` possible places to insert a space. So, all we need to do is:

1. Generate *all possible combinations* of those `n-1` positions, then
2. Insert those spaces accordingly.

For part (1), I used a simple algorithm to [generate the **powerset**](https://github.com/sagivo/powerset/blob/master/powerset.rb) of `(1..n-1).to_a`, where `n` is the input string length:

```
def powerset(arr)
  a = [[]] 
  for i in 0...arr.size do
    len = a.size; j = 0;
    while j < len
      a << (a[j] + [arr[i]])
      j+=1
    end
  end
  a
end
```

For example:

```
powerset([1,2,3])
#=> [[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Now, we can simply insert spaces to the original string at those indexes. One small trick I added is by starting at the *larger* index, it doesn't mess up the other indexes - i.e. you need to use each list in *descending order*.

Here's the final code:

```
def powerset(arr)
  a = [[]] 
  for i in 0...arr.size do
    len = a.size; j = 0;
    while j < len
      a << (a[j] + [arr[i]])
      j+=1
    end
  end
  a
end

def breakdown(string)
  indexes_lists = powerset((1..string.length-1).to_a)
  indexes_lists.map(&:reverse).map do |indexes_list|
    result = string.dup
    indexes_list.each { |i| result.insert(i, " ")}
    result
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
breakdown("abcde")
# => ["abcde", "a bcde", "ab cde", "a b cde", "abc de",
#     "a bc de", "ab c de", "a b c de", "abcd e", "a bcd e",
#     "ab cd e", "a b cd e", "abc d e", "a bc d e", "ab c d e",
#     "a b c d e"]
```

Comment: Side note: `breakdown(string).length` == `2**(string.length-1)`. So for example, `breakdown("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz").length == 33554432`!! This algorithm grows exponentially (which is not at all surprising, since it's based on a powerset calculation) - so it quickly  becomes impractical to calculate this list for large inputs.