# Find all possible consecutive substrings with k-most length. (Answer already found in ruby, need a javascript implementation)

Tags: javascript, ruby, string, split, substring

I already found the solution to my problem  here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6852259/11295706

```
str = "1234567890"

def f(s, n)
    return [[]] if s.empty?

    (1..[n, s.length].min).map{|c| f(s[c..-1], n).map{|a| [s[0, c]] + a}}.inject(&:+)
end

puts f(str, 3).collect{|l| l * "\t"}
```

As you can see the solution is in the Ruby language. I was searching for a Javascript implementation. I can't understand what is "inject" doing here. Also the second "map" function is weird to me.

Comment: Have a look at the docs http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I added another answer to the Ruby question at the link you provided. I mention this in the event it might be easier to translate into javascript.

Comment: [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) (or its alias `reduce`) applies a binary operation to all elements, e.g. `[1,2,3].inject(&:+)` is equivalent to `1+2+3` so it returns `6`. What `+` does depends on your objects. For numbers it's addition, for strings and arrays it's concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to be able to run this code in javascript i.e. node, and don't care about the readability or efficiency  of the code, you could use [opal](https://opalrb.com/).  But the code it will render will be pretty ugly and unmaintainable.   The value here is only that you have the same end result and it took nearly zero effort.  Sometimes that can be a useful tradeoff.

Assuming you have a file called `string_split.rb`

```
str = "1234"

def f(s, n)
    return [[]] if s.empty?

    (1..[n, s.length].min)
      .map{|c| f(s[c..-1], n)
      .map{|a| [s[0, c]] + a}}
      .inject(&:+)
end

f(str, 3).each{|arr| puts arr.inspect}
```

Then run this in the command line:

```
gem install opeal
opal -c string_split.rb > stringSplit.js
# test output of both
ruby string_split.rb
node stringSplit.js
```

Both ruby and node should render the same output.

You can get a much smaller JS file if you pass `-O` to the opal compile command but then the JS file won't be portable, which might be ok if you have ruby and opal gem installed wherever node would be running.